# Netty: configure timeout for channel read per channel

Tags: java, netty

I am using Netty framework and implemented client and server. I am making many connections as high as 1000. I want to configure timeout values in multiple places. Some of them i am able to figure out. So, here's the netty behavior of my netty implementation:
1. Many async connections starts from client with the timeout(configured using ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS).
2. Those client connections which are able to connect sends HTTP request using channelActive and receives response using channelRead0.

Problem - I want to place timeout value between sending the request and receiving the data for a particular channel.
I read the netty documentation and come up with two solutions:
1. https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelConfig.html#setConnectTimeoutMillis-int-
2. https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/timeout/ReadTimeoutHandler.html

I am confused which option to choose and which one is better or is there any other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set multiple limits (most likely). As you already found out you may want to set a connect timeout via `setConnectTimeoutMillis` but also have a `ChannelDuplexHandler` that will ensure you receive the response to a request in the expected time. You may also want to have a look at `IdleStateHandler` which will allow to fire events through the `ChannelPipeline` if the `Channel` idles for too long.

Comment: Just one clarification - setConnectTimeoutMillissets the connect timeout of the channel in milliseconds. Now this channel includes the time to connect, write and read which is different from ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS. Right?
Reference - https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelConfig.html#setConnectTimeoutMillis-int-